# Broadcast receiver works on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an application that i'm using broadcast receiver to start an service.

When i run it on ADV (emulator) it works fine, but when i try to run it on device, not working.

I've tried with android 2.3.3, 4.0.3, 5.0 and many diferents devices, no success.

**MANIFEST**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />      
<application>
<receiver android:name="com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions.MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
    android:name="com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions.NotificationService" >
</service>
</application>
```

**RECEIVER**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.i("Script", "Passou RECEIVER");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    context.startService(i);

}
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

public static final int time = 15 * 1000;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE CREATE");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE START");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE DESTROY");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE COMMAND");
    final Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(time);
                    showNotification();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public void showNotification() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Polifrete")
            .setContentText("Test Notification.")
            .setSmallIcon(
                    com.polifrete.polifreteandroid.R.drawable.ic_actionbar)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify((int)(Math.random()*10000), n.build());

}
}
```

Comment: after installing it on your device, did you start manually your app at least once, before reboot?

Comment: already done it too, ive closed the application and started it manually and nothing

Comment: Does your app have any activities?

Comment: I needed to turn off my phone and turn on again and it works, but Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Is your application supporting external storage?
If yes change it to Internal only

Comment: Already done that on manifest...     android:installLocation="internalOnly"